# Bundle values in array using for loop and "index" in string

Tags: python, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

I have this operation that I don't know how to do. I looked deep but I never found an answer to my question.

How do you iterate an "index" in a string ? Let me explain what I mean.

I got a lot of separate values that I'd like to bundle in an array, and theses separate values are named with a number in the end.

Here is an exemple of what I'd like to do

```
freq1 = 1
freq2 = 10
freq3 = 5
freq4 = 4
...
freq46 = 6
freq47 = 5

for i in range(1,47):
    freq =  ... ? ...
```

What should I put in my loop function so that it returns me this :

```
freq = [1, 10, 5, 4, ... , 6, 5]
```

Thanks a lot if you take the time to answer !

Antoine

Answer (score 0):

Use `eval` it converts a string to a python object

```
freq = []
for f in range(1, 47):
    freq.append(eval("freq{}".format(f)))
```